# how to compile the tutorial program on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorboard

After configuring the tensorflow, I tried to run the command 
`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer`

But an error occured which I tried every possible but failed to solve.

> **ERROR**: Skipping '//tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer': error loading package 'tensorflow/cc': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1042
>           _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 975, in _create_local_cuda_repository
>           _host_compiler_includes(repository_ctx, cc)
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 145, in _host_compiler_includes
>           get_cxx_inc_directories(repository_ctx, cc)
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 120, in get_cxx_inc_directories
>           set(includes_cpp)
>
> The `set` constructor for depsets is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the `depset` constructor instead. You can temporarily enable the deprecated `set` constructor by passing the flag --incompatible_disallow_set_constructor=false
>
> **WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.**
>
> **ERROR**: error loading package 'tensorflow/cc': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': **no such package** '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 1042
>           _create_local_cuda_repository(repository_ctx)
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 975, in _create_local_cuda_repository
>           _host_compiler_includes(repository_ctx, cc)
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 145, in _host_compiler_includes
>           get_cxx_inc_directories(repository_ctx, cc)
>
> File "/home/manyz/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl", line 120, in get_cxx_inc_directories
>           set(includes_cpp)
>
> The `set` constructor for depsets is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the `depset` constructor instead. You can temporarily enable the deprecated `set` constructor by passing the flag --incompatible_disallow_set_constructor=false
>
> **INFO: Elapsed time: 2.293s**
>
> **FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)**
>       currently loading: tensorflow/cc

Note that: I've installed the CUDA8.0, cuDNN 5.0 and Bazel 0.6.0, My system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I assume you selected yes for cuda during configure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is already an issue open for this problem: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11859. Last comment says that the issue can be fixed by editing line 120 in `tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl`. If that doesn't help I'd subscribe to the issue and wait for a fix.

Comment: acually, it seems that when I edit the .bzl file, there will be a lot more files to be edited. I finally rolled my bazel back to 0.5.4 and it works. Anyway, thanks.